# Angular JS | what to pass in ng-click ternary operator to do nothing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to enable ng-click based on a condition using ternary operator (?:)

`ng-click="hasPermission?Update():...."`

In last parameter of ternary operator what can I pass so that nothing would happen.

Also, I don't want to create any dummy function in my JS or to write any irrelevant condition as 1=1

Answer (score 25):

*angular.noop()* was provided to address your scenario:

```
<div ng-click="hasPermission ? Update() : angular.noop()">
```

noop() is a function that peforms no operations.

[Documention Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.noop)

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this instead:

```
ng-click="hasPermission && Update()"
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not:

```
ng-click="Update()"

$scope.Update = function(){
   if($scope.hasPermission){
    // do something
   }
}
```

It will be easier to:
1.Debug.
2.Read your code.
3.Add conditions to your code in the feature.
4.Clean your htmls.

etc...

Comment: This seems like the most *Angular* way to do it. Logic like this shouldn't really be in the view.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you write just

```
ng-click="hasPermission && Update()"
```

It will check weather `hasPermission` is not false/undefined/null it will call the `update()`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/XqDxG/1156/)

Just change the value of `$scope.has` in above demo & see.

Answer (score 2):

Terrnary operator in ng-click you should write like this

```
<div ng-click="hasPermission ? Update() : DontUpdate()">
```